# Empty parameters list for model

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying to implement an autoencoder neural network based on convolutional layers and max pooling & unpooling to encode and decode images on greyscale (MNIST images). I have defined its class `ConvAEUnpool` as follows:

```
class ConvAEUnpool(nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvAEUnpool, self).__init__()

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        #Coder
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, stride=3, padding=1),  # b, 16, 10, 10
        self.maxPool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, return_indices=True),  # b, 16, 5, 5
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 8, 3, stride=2, padding=1),  # b, 8, 3, 3
        self.maxPool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=1, return_indices=True)  # b, 8, 2, 2
        
        # Decoder
        self.maxUnpool1 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=1) # b, 8, 3, 3
        self.deConv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d( 8, 16, 3, stride=2),  # b, 16, 5, 5
        self.maxUnpool2 = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=2) # b, 16, 10, 10
        self.deConv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 1, 3, stride=3, padding=1),  # b, 1, 28, 28
        

    def forward(self, x):
        # Code
        x = self.Conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x, idx1 = self.MaxPool1(x)
        x = self.Conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x, idx2 = self.MaxPool2(x)

        # Decode
        x = self.MaxUnpool1(x, idx2)
        x = self.DeConv1(x)
        x = self.MaxUnpool2(x, idx1)
        x = self.DeConv2(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        
        return x
```

For some reason, when I create an instance and try to select an optimizer for its parameters, as follows:

```
model = ConvAEUnpool().to(device)

# create an optimizer object
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

it raises the following error:
*ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list*

I've done some search and have tried by using a nn.ModuleList():

```
self.nn_layers = nn.ModuleList(modules=[self.Conv1, self.MaxPool1, self.Conv2, self.MaxPool2, 
                                        self.MaxUnpool1, self.DeConv1, self.MaxUnpool2, self.DeConv2])
```

but I am not sure how to make it work with a MaxUnpool2d, as I need to pass the indices of the previuos MaxPool2d layer. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You have put commas (',') in your `__init__` method, at the end of most instructions. Remove them and `model.parameters()` will work just fine